# Ionic does not accept animation attribute in ion-view

Tags: animation, ionic-framework

I have **ion-view** template which is referenced from main menu of the app.

In second view i have attribute:

```
<ion-view title="Settings" animation="slide-in-up">
```

But page is loaded with default animation.

I tried to remove attribute animation from body tag, but without luck, animation is still same (i tried it in several browsers and android devices).

```
<body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
```

Could somebody tell me how can i set animation by right way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is all of what you're looking for, but I was able to find [$ionicAnimation documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicAnimation/). It also sounds like the Ionic team has been doing some [major work that effects transitions](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/please-help-test-angular-1-3-improved-transitions-cached-views-repost/13561), which might be why the docs have been down.